# Possibility to simulate -Werror option behavior with GCC 3.4?

Tags: c, warnings, gcc3

Is there any hope to force GCC 3.4 compiler to make all warnings into errors like GCC's 4.4 -Werror option does ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you don't upgrade to 4.4 ? This would be the perfect solution :)

Comment: I can't, because third party libs we use aren't compatible with gcc 4.4 :-(

Comment: gcc 3.4.6 accepts `-Werror` (see [bottom of manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)); gcc 3.3.6 [also accepts it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) !!

Comment: Oops, somehow I missed that feature :-) Very thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pmg said -

> gcc 3.4.6 accepts -Werror (see bottom of manual); gcc 3.3.6 also
>   accepts it !!

Real credits should go to pmg, but thanks for everybody else also :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it and return an error if gcc wrote anything to stderr.

Execute GCC, redirect stderr in a file, cat the file to stderr:

```
temp=$(tempfile)
trap rm "$temp" EXIT

gcc "$@" 2>"$temp"
ret=$?

cat "$temp" >&2
```

Return gcc's exit status if it's not 0:

```
if [ "$ret" != 0 ]; then
    exit $ret;
}
```

Return 1 if the file is not empty:

```
if [ $(stat --format=%s "$temp") != "0" ]; then
    exit 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly hack, just grep "warning:"

```
gcc files.c 2>&1 | grep "warning:" && exit 1
```

Replace exit 1 with what it should do when warnings are found.